# Cannot make changes on Dashboard

Tags: dashboard

We recently decided to revamp our website. We are intending to make changes to the content and the design of the webpage. However, after logging into wp-admin, there are only 3 things we see is Dashboard, Jetpack and Profile. There's nothing else we can do with the website.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you might have been logged in as a user with insufficient access to the content. you need to login as an administrator.. check your users database.. for details